# limits of algebraic varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, big-picture

I'm looking for a reference which deals with limits of families of algebraic varieties as the degree increases (or at least keywords from this subject).

For the kind of example I have in mind, consider the exponential function as a convergent power series e^x=1+x+x^2/2!+...  on the interval [-1;1] say, and consider the varieties A0:={(x,y)\in\R^2 s.t. y=1},  A1:={(x,y)\in\R^2 s.t. y=1+x}, A2:={(x,y)\in\R^2 s.t. y=1+x+x^2/2!}... which converge (in the euclidean topology) to the graph of the exponential (as in the picture [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [On the limit of families of algebraic subvarieties with unbounded volume](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/doc/limits.pdf), to appear in Astérisque.

Comment: Informative text and references to the literature, thanks!